# IE9 scrolling to top when css:hover has an color attribute

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I've found a really strange bug;
See my sample at http://lunchbestellen.bekijkonzesite.nl/test/index .
When you scroll down and hover over an element the scrollbar goes back to the top.
When I remove the hover-styles in the CSS it doesn't.
Somebody please help... I'm pulling my hair out.

With regards,
Jeroen